# Codename One: wait until a given boolean is true

Tags: codenameone

I need to wait until a given boolean is true. That boolean is updated by a listener. All the code is inside the EDT, so something like the following is not applicable:

```
while (!myBoolean) {
    Util.sleep(100);
}
```

How can I stop a flow of execution inside the EDT (in a correct way), until the given boolean becomes true?

Comment: I solved my problem changing the logic of the code, however this is a general question that can be valid if we have some code inside listener that should wait that a given variable changes its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
invokeAndBlock(() -> {
    while (!myBoolean) {
       Util.sleep(100);
    }
});
```

A better approach would be:

```
timer = UITimer.schedule(100, true, () -> {
   if(myBoolean) {
      timer.cancel();
      runThisMethod();
   }
});
```

A more elaborate question is "why not add a listener"?

Since the boolean is changed from a listener why not add a listener after the listener that triggers that and do the work there?